# Difference between test(&p) and test(p) when passing a proc object?

Tags: ruby

If I have this:

```
pr = Proc.new { puts 'test' }
```

What is the difference between:

```
def test(arg)
  arg.call
end

test(pr)
```

and

```
def test(&arg)
  arg.call
end

test(&pr)
```

Both return the same thing, so when would I use one or the other?

Comment: You asked the exact same question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25672522/when-to-use-method-vs-methodblockand, and it was answered.

Comment: 7stud That is not the same question. My doubts here are why do we call (arg) or (&arg).

Comment: You don't get to decide how to call a method.  A method is defined to be called a certain way.  In your second example, creating a proc, then converting the proc to a block: `test(&pr)` is poorly written code because you can just call the method with a block: `test {puts 'test'}`--thus avoiding having to create the proc and then converting it to a block.  Of course, if the code that calls test() gets a proc from somewhere else, then the only choice is to call test() with the proc: `test(&pr)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`test(arg)` accepts **one argument**, You pass a `Proc` object to method `test` method by `test(pr)`.

`test(&arg)` accepts **zero argument** but accepts **a block**, You pass the block by `&pr` to method `test` by `test(&pr)`.

`&pr` converts Proc `pr` to a block when passing to a method.

***[Further Reading.](http://weblog.raganwald.com/2008/06/what-does-do-when-used-as-unary.html)***

Comment: Shouldn't you look at this post and fix its formatting?  I think you meant to use **bold with two asterisks** instead of h2 tags.

Comment: @DavidGrayson OK, I just want to make the point bigger than just bold at first ^^

Comment: Note also, `def test; yield; end`, `test &pr #=> test`.

Comment: ``&pr`` converts Proc to a block? How come ``pr.class`` is Proc inside then?

Comment: @HommerSmith &pr is treated as a block when passing, not `pr`.

Comment: Hommer: `pr` is an object and its type is `Proc`.  Every method has a single slot for passing in a block when you call it, and if you want to put `pr` in that slot then you use `&pr` when calling the method, but `pr` itself is still a Proc.  There is no "block" class.

Comment: A concise explanation of `&` would be:  When used during the calling of a method, `&` lets you pass a Proc to a method's block slot.  When used during the definition of a method's arguments, `&` lets you capture the block passed to a method and use it as a local variable which has a name and is of class `Proc`.

Answer (score 2):

The `&` alters a block into a proc and an object into a block via `to_proc` method.

The difference between the two is that in the first one, you pass a proc argument directly. In the second one, you pass a proc as a block to the method, which is converted back into a proc when it is received. In the first one, the proc remains the same object, but in the second one, the original proc and the received proc are different objects.

In cases like this when you have a proc that is passed around in a variable/constant, it is better to use the first one because converting a proc into a block and back into a proc as in the second one is redundant calculation. When you want to directly pass a block, you should use the second option.